# Passing the data via prepareForSegue:sender: and assigning initial values to outlets

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I'm working with existing code and I see we push some viewController with performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: and then we pass the data to destination viewController:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

  if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[DetailsViewController class]]) {

    DetailsViewController *detailsVC = (DetailsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    detailsVC.detailsData = someData; 
  }
```

Then imagine we have a custom setDetailsData setter in destinationViewController:

```
- (void)setDetailsData:(NSDictionary *)detailsData {

  _detailsData = detailsData;
  // other data customisation stuff

  // Then we need to assign initial values to outlets
  // The view is not loaded yet, so we are forcing to initialise this view. This will result in viewDidLoad being called 
  self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

  // Set outlet values
  self.firstNameLabel.text = [_detailsData …];
  self.lastNameLabel.text = [_detailsData …];
}
```

The interesting part viewDidLoad of destinationViewController is not called yet at the time setDetailsData: is executed inside prepareForSegue. So we can’t assign values for these outlets because they are not initialised yet (nil). So in order to make it work there's a little hack:

```
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

This forces to initialise the view and outlets. I agree, having such custom setter both for making customisations of inner data, and assigning outlets is convenient (everything is in one place), but I'm worried it's breaking the normal flow of view initialisation. We should pass only the data. Values to the outlets should be assigned in viewDidLoad method separately. What is you opinion of that, is it normal? I was unable to find any restrictions of that in Apple docs, but still doubt about it.

Comment: Just do the initial setting up in `viewDidLoad` surely?

Answer (score 1):

just remember to have your property set as strong :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary * detailsData;
```

and do your UI updates in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like it that much, but if it works it works!

I mean, the fact that your code is working and is not buggy (assuming it's not) proves that the *technique* is a viable way of solving this little problem.

But on the other hand, and this is my personal opinion, it makes the code look dirty. When you see that line of code

```
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

you would think "*oh, this must enable the user to interact with the UI, it must be disabled by default*", but noooo, it's a hack to initialize the UI. And since we often copy-paste our own code, we create a bad habit.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already saving the reference to the details data away, my preference (and the "norm") would be to move the view initializations (self.firstName.test....) into viewDidLoad.  That way you're guaranteed that the views have already been loaded and are not yet displayed AND you eliminate the reliance on side effects from "self.view.userInteractionEnabled =..."  If you really insist on doing it there, at least use "if(!self.isViewLoaded) [self loadView]"